# How to change WooCommerce loader/spinner with pure CSS loader?

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the default WooCommerce loader (see attached image below) by a custom pure CSS loader like one of theese: https://cssloaders.github.io ?
Thank you in advance.[image]

Most of solutions needs a .gif image like this:

```
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
.woocommerce .loader:before {
  background-image:url('path/to/your/image.gif');
}
```

I dont now if is't possible with pure CSS.